# RAID5 (3xHard-Disk) status FAILED suddenly, what should do?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, raid-5, recovery, intel-rst

There is a data server in a PC case just for purpose of synchronization and sharing data in a local network that is running 24/7 except in case of power outages.

I did not install the RAID configuration on it. The machine was given to me and it already had Windows on it.

I only touch the machine periodically to backup data.
Again, I do not have any information about how the RAID was set up.

OS: Windows 7
SSD: 250GB (Boot)
HDD: 3 x 2TB WD Red (RAID5 - As it look)
Board: ASUS P10S WS
CPU: Intel i5-7400

After a power loss I was faced with a "F1 Error" and told to check BIOS, furthermore windows would not boot up.

So:

- I checked the BIOS and turned on **"Intel Rapid Storage Technology"**.
- Windows came up, other drives exist but:
  [image: RAID5 Failed]
  [image]
  .
- Then after a restart I see this:
  [image]

1. Why the RAID Implementation failed by itself?
2. By this status, How i recover the RAID, without losing data?
   2.1. If not, can i recover all of data and make a new RAID?
3. Any third advise for handling the situation?

Best Regards

Comment: “Why the RAID Implementation failed by itself?” - 2/3 disks failed in a RAID5. Data is gone . If you initialized the disks that would be the reason

Comment: This is why a recovery plan should be created. A recovery plan is more than simply having a RAID controller.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is i never knew how it initialized in first, and i just accept some IT works here for safety backup of data inside windows. And as i said just one day without any touch of myself, after power of the area gone off & on and the system turned on (i still don't know by employers or the motherboard sets). the problem appeared.

Comment: @EricF you mean better to not have any kind of RAID in a data server?

Comment: @MMMahdy-PAPION No. You should have a detailed recovery plan with scenarios. For example, what should be done when drive 1 fails? Perform a set of actions. What to do if all 3 drives fail? Should also have a set of actions (such as grab your offsite backup). This plan is much more important than any piece of hardware or software by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the RAID Implementation failed by itself?

The standard answer would be:
Two drive failed simultaneously. You cannot rebuild a RAID5 configuration with just one spare when two drive fails.

My answer is:
But I guess two simultaneously failing drives are rare.
Usually there is no crystal ball diagnosis.
Luckily you mentioned some critical information, your F1 Bios error.

I pretend that your RAID failed due to your negligence.
You received a machine with an unkown history.
Your BIOS forgot its RAID setting of the SATA controller.

## Your failure

1. You should have saved the data on the machine.
2. You should haved saved or written down all BIOS settings when receiving the machine. Your BIOS battery was already so empty that it was unable to buffer the settings during the power loss.
3. You should have replaced the buffer battery, typically a CR2032 by a quality western product, like Panasonic, Sanyo, Sony, Varta or Renata.
4. You should have measured the voltage of your old and new CR2032 battery with a multimeter.
5. You should have restarted the machine with drives disconnected an run the BIOS function "load setup defaults".
6. You should have changed your specific settings that differ from the standard settings, especially the mode of your SATA controller which has two different settings, AHCI and RAID. Unfortunately there may be more controller-related settings than just AHCI and RAID.

## What to do now

1. Remove every disk of your RAID configuration.
2. Check your SMART parameters by connecting your drives on a different machine as described here
   https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10910
   and post them on Superuser.
3. Duplicate each disk of your RAID on a different machine on sector level using ddrescue under linux.
4. Restart your RAID machine without disks and follow the steps outlined under "Your failure" section 2.
5. After restarting the RAID machine with the RAID disks reinserted there should be no BIOS error.
6. Check in BIOS if the RAID configuration of your three drives is recognized. If yes, let Windows start and check if you find your volumes having a file system and the content you expect.

In case of failure use RAID recovery software to read out the data and save it to a different location.
Every sector that is unreadable on at least two disks is lost and there is no recovery for its content. If you agree on restoring even broken data a professional lab could read that out if your WD10EFRX complies with some special ATA commands.
Keep in mind that in that case the content of the broken sectors may be more or less altered.

Comment: @OP If you are going to go to the trouble of measuring the new CMOS battery, a new CR2032 cell will have a voltage of at least 3.1 V. If the "new" one is below 3.0 V, I suggest getting a different one. And make a calendar entry to replace it every four years. And make a backup of the BIOS once you have the computer in a working configuation.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the advise. Is the backup of BIOS including the RAID array configuration? This [ASUS Saving profiles of BIOS Settings](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1046388/) is enough or it need some kind of exporting to a file?

Comment: @MMMahdy-PAPION I can't say for certain, but you can always write down the settings and tape them to the inside of the computer case.